# Export Datatable to Excel 2007 with C# and StreamWriter

Tags: excel, export, streamwriter

I have a winform application and i want export my datatable to office 2007(.xlsx) format using stream writer and savefiledialog.But when i work to open excel file i take this error:file format or file extension is not valid.

Fx_3saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel 2007-2010 files (.xlsx)|*.xlsx;            Fx_3saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "xlsx";

```
        if (Fx_3saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dsUrunTableAdapters.PF_FormDegerTableAdapter adapter = new dsUrunTableAdapters.PF_FormDegerTableAdapter();
            dsUrun.PF_FormDegerDataTable degertable = new dsUrun.PF_FormDegerDataTable();
            adapter.Fill(degertable);

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Fx_3saveFileDialog.FileName,true);
            //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(dialog.FileName);

            writer.Write("<html>");
            writer.Write("<head>");
            writer.Write("</head>");
            writer.Write("<body>");

            writer.Write("<table>");

            foreach( DataColumn c in degertable.Columns )
            {
                //writer.Write(c.Caption);
                writer.Write("<td>");
                writer.Write(c.Caption);
                writer.Write("</td>");

            }

            writer.Write("</table>");
            writer.Write("</body>");
            writer.Write("</html>");

            //writer.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow r in degertable.Rows)
            {
                //writer.Write(r[degertable.SecilebilecekDegerlerColumn].ToString());
            }

            writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel files are zipped files which contain an open format. You're writing an HTML page and giving it an xlsx extension, that won't work.

Either you have to use COM and manipulate Excel to add the cells, or the easiest, output your table as a CSV text file (comma separated file) which Excel can read very easily.